# How can i solve an error "pdo exception could not find the driver" on laravel migration?

Tags: laravel

I am studying laravel framework by myself and am trying to build simple blog with it. However, I found an error when i migrate the tables to the database(I am using mysql). When i run the command-  php artisan migrate -
on ubuntu 14.04, i got these message

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = laravel-blog and table_name = migrations)
```

and

```
[PDOException]         
could not find driver
```

I tried the last two days to find the answer on youtube, google, here in stackoverflow,etc.; but i can't.

So someone has a skill on laravel, please help me. 
Thanks

Comment: Be sure to configure the 'default' key in app/config/database.php

Comment: Did you create the database?

Comment: @jackowski ... in app/config/database.php the 'default' is mysql  and also i created the database. But i cannot connect it

Comment: is there a key `DB_CONNECTION=mysql` in your .env?

Comment: Do you have the mysql service running? Are you sure you .env file has all config needed like DB_USERNAME or DB_PASSWORD?

Comment: @milo52... yes there is. I tried also in php.ini file but i donot know exactly which extension will add and remove.

Comment: @jackowski ... you can see it     DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=simplonco

Comment: Check if you have this line uncommented on you php.ini: `;extension=pdo_mysql.so`

Comment: I dont have any extension with pdo on php.ini

Comment: I have these extensions on my php.ini file  extension=modulename.extension
;
; For example, on Windows:
;
;   extension=msql.dll
;
; ... or under UNIX:
;
;   extension=msql.so
;
; ... or with a path:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/msql.so

Comment: What you showed looks like just examples. Are you sure that's all you have on your php.ini file? If so, that's why it's not working.

Comment: Not all, there is a lot of things... but i copy and paste here only the extensions... I didn't find any extensions with pdo.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a similar problem (again).

Just in case this helps people, you need the following packages for PHP on Laravel 5.5 (I use yum, but feel free to change use apt-get if thats what you prefer).

```
php71.x86_64                         7.1.7-1.26.amzn1              @amzn-updates
php71-cli.x86_64                     7.1.7-1.26.amzn1              @amzn-updates
php71-common.x86_64                  7.1.7-1.26.amzn1              @amzn-updates
php71-json.x86_64                    7.1.7-1.26.amzn1              @amzn-updates
php71-mbstring.x86_64                7.1.7-1.26.amzn1              @amzn-updates
php71-mysqlnd.x86_64                 7.1.7-1.26.amzn1              @amzn-updates
php71-pdo.x86_64                     7.1.7-1.26.amzn1              @amzn-updates
php71-process.x86_64                 7.1.7-1.26.amzn1              @amzn-updates
php71-xml.x86_64                     7.1.7-1.26.amzn1              @amzn-updates
```

The way to check this is `yum list installed | grep php`. The package I was missing was `php71-mysqlnd`

Answer (score 0):

Open `php.ini` file and enable `extension=pdo_mysql`